# How To Enable Disk Encryption For F2FS Formatted Drives?

Tags: encryption, f2fs

I'm using the F2FS filesystem for one of my SSDs and apparently encryption support was added for it in Linux kernel. I can't find any information on it other than that it exists (http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1506.3/00598.html).

Answer (score 0):

F2FS supports file-level encryption. If you are looking for full disk encryption, EXT4 would be what you are looking for.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/F2FS